# How to hide "image" custom field if empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I created an unordered list of custom fields and I wish to hide them if they are empty. For text custom fields I used the code:

```
<?php if (get_field('phone') != '') { ?>
  <li><strong>Phone: </strong><?php the_field('phone'); ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

However, I have a custom field which is for images, like this:

```
<li><strong>Logo: </strong><img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>"></img></li>
```

How can I hide the field if no image was uploaded (obviously, the above code won't work)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `the_field('logo')` will return a falsy value if there are no images

```
if (the_field('logo')) {
    ?>
        <li><strong>Logo: </strong><img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>"></img></li>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Well, that works nicely on hiding the image. However, if there is an image, it will display it's url. So, instead of using the_field, I used get_field and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: @Cthulhu no problem. Don't forget to accept the answer that has helped you the most by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: Of course, mate! But you should edit your answer to be accurate.

Comment: You don't have to accept mine either, if the other answer helped you most you should accept it. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Well, both of the answers work, but yours was the one that actually helped me. With your answer I could think and evolve my skills. I only tried the other solution to experiment. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be

```
<?php if (get_field('logo') != ''): ?>
      <li><strong>Logo: </strong><img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>"></img></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: using get_field() instead of the_field() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( get_field('field_name') ): ?>
<p>My field value: <?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that have working code plus helpful explanations. 
In this case, it would be worthwhile explaining this answer to a 5 year old.