# remove unwanted space from page

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was working on this site in a custom template using all the possibilities of advanced custom filed plugin **[MY Site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/naturalorganiclifestyles)**
i have created a few custom fields and called the filed values using the following code.

```
<div class="category-images"><?php echo get_field( "category_heading_1" ); ?></div>
<div class="images">
<?php 

$image1 = get_field('image_1'); 
$image2 = get_field('image_2');
$image3 = get_field('image_3');
$image4 = get_field('image_4');
$image5 = get_field('image_5');
$image6 = get_field('image_6');
$image7 = get_field('image_7');
$image8 = get_field('image_8');
$image9 = get_field('image_9');
?>

<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_1" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image1['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image2['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_3" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image3['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
</div>
  <div class="images_txt">
    <div class="img_txt"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_1" ); ?></b> </div>
    <div class="img_txt1"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2" ); ?></b> </div>
    <div class="img_txt2"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_3" ); ?></b> </div>
</div> 
<div class="images">
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_4" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image4['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_5" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image5['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_6" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image6['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="images_txt"> 
 <div class="img_txt"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_4" ); ?> </b></div>
   <div class="img_txt1"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_5" ); ?> </b></div>
   <div class="img_txt2"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_6" ); ?> </b></div>
</div> 
<div class="images">
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_7" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image7['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_8" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image8['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_9" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image9['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="images_txt">  
<div class="img_txt"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_7" ); ?> </b></div>
  <div class="img_txt1"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_8" ); ?></b> </div>
  <div class="img_txt2"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_9" ); ?></b> </div>
   </div>

   <div class="category-images"><?php echo get_field( "category_heading_2" ); ?></div>
<div class="images">
<?php 

$image_21 = get_field('image_2(1)'); 
$image_22 = get_field('image_2(2)'); 
$image_23 = get_field('image_2(3)'); 
$image_24 = get_field('image_2(4)'); 
$image_25 = get_field('image_2(5)'); 
$image_26 = get_field('image_2(6)'); 
$image_27 = get_field('image_2(7)'); 
$image_28 = get_field('image_2(8)'); 
$image_29 = get_field('image_2(9)'); 

?>

<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(1)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_21['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(2)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_22['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(3)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_23['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="images_txt">
<div class="img_txt"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(1)" ); ?></b> </div>
<div class="img_txt1"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(2)" ); ?></b> </div>
<div class="img_txt2"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(3)" ); ?></b> </div>
</div> 
<div class="images">
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(4)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_24['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(5)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_25['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(6)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_26['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="images_txt"> 
 <div class="img_txt"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(4)" ); ?> </b></div>
  <div class="img_txt1"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(5)" ); ?> </b></div>
  <div class="img_txt2"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(6)" ); ?> </b></div>
</div> 
<div class="images">
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(7)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_27['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(8)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_28['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
<div class="img1"><a href="<?php echo get_field( "image_link_2(9)" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_29['url']; ?>" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="images_txt">  
<div class="img_txt"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(7)" ); ?> </b></div>
  <div class="img_txt1"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(8)" ); ?></b> </div>
  <div class="img_txt2"><b><?php echo get_field( "image_heading_2(9)" ); ?></b> </div>
   </div>
```

So in my case I have added only 3 fileds as custom filed from backend.I have assigned it 9 because there can be future additions.as i have only 3 products and when its displaying at the front end the page is taking space for the fileds which I have not entered.The source code shows the div for each custom fileds even if it has nothing to dispaly.So the user have scroll down a bit more to reach footer.You can see it [HERE](http://constantin-entertainment.info/naturalorganiclifestyles/) .Is there any way the height of that div increases automatically when future images are added.Please help,Thanks!!

Comment: You would be far better off setting this up as a repeater field, do you have the repeater field add on? (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U should check the variable like $image1
which returns the value of first imaged
check `if $image1==NULL or $image1=='' then do nothing else display image`

you can check here
[How to hide "image" custom field if empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271968/how-to-hide-image-custom-field-if-empty5:26) PM
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/
these could be your right answers.

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to change the PHP, so that if there is no image, it will not print the HTML at all.

```
if($image1 != null && $image2 != null && $image3 != null){
    echo '<div class="images">';
    echo '<div class="img1"><a href="'.get_field( "image_link_1" ).'"><img src=".'$image1['url'].'" /></a></div>';
    echo '<div class="img1"><a href="'.get_field( "image_link_2" ).'"><img src=".'$image2['url'].'" /></a></div>';
    echo '<div class="img1"><a href="'.get_field( "image_link_3" ).'"><img src=".'$image3['url'].'" /></a></div>';
    ...
}
```

You could even improve the code with a couple of tricks:
(I have not tested it, so it might need some adjustments).

```
<?php
    //Settings to set the amount of categories / images per category:
    //ACF might have a way of providing these numbers, I am not sure.
    $CATEGORIES = 2;
    $IMAGESPERCATEGORY = 9; // Must be divisible by three.

    for($i=1; i<$CATEGORIES+1; $i++){
?>

<?php  
        $images = array();
        $links = array();
        $headings = array();
        for($j =0; $j < $IMAGESPERCATEGORY; $j++){
            $img = get_field('image_'.$i.'_'.$j); //The file format is 'image_cat_no' so category 1 image 4 would be 'image_1_4';
            $link = get_field('image_link_'.$i.'_'.$j);
            $heading = get_field('image_heading_'.$i.'_'.$j);
            if($img != null && $link != null && $heading != null){
                //Data is there, push them to arrays:
                array_push($images, $img);
                array_push($links, $link);
                array_push($headings, $heading);
            }else{
                //TODO: Some data is not there, provide default values or some fault handling.
            }
        }
?>

        <div class="category-images"><?php echo get_field( "category_heading_".($i) ); ?></div>
<?php
        for($y = 0; $y < $IMAGESPERCATEGORY / 3; $y++){
?>
            <div class="images">
<?php
            //Print <img> tags
            for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
                echo '<div class="img1"><a href="'.$links[$x].'"><img src=".'$images[$x]['url'].'" /></a></div>';
            }
?>
        </div>

        <div class="images_txt">
<?php
        //Print text
        for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
            echo '<div class="img_txt'.($x!=0 ? ($x+1).'' : '').'"><b>'.$headings[$x].'</b></div>';
        }
?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This question isn't about jQuery, WordPress or advanced-custom-fields.

It's just CSS. Add a class called "hidden" to the hidden elements and hide them using corresponding CSS code: `.hidden { display:none; }`

Comment: but what if i add images in future .it will be still display none.so i need to go and remove the class each time i add new images? thats not cool